# Analytics and AdSense Integration

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-adsense, integration

I tried to link my Analytics and AdSense accounts. But there exist a problem. Analytics redirects me to AdSense account and AdSense is redirects me to Analytics. And this is unlimited loop.

On this AdSense screen I couldn't find link account button. What is the problem? Do you have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Are these two accounts running on the same Google account?
2. Did you check this box on the GA's account settings?

[image: share data GA]

Comment: 1. Of course same account. 2. Where is this setup located ?

Comment: GA-->Admin-->Account settings